# The RDS instance CPU is 99%

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, query-performance

Query taking a long time to execute in AWS RDS

The one query is taking too much time around 3 minutes. Db is hosted in AWS RDS with 2cpu and 4GB ram (t2. medium)

The Query Sample is

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'Day',
        sum(people_count) as 'count'"
    from  avg_people_pass
    where  log_date >= #startDate
      and  log_date <= #endDate
```

appreciate your help because it lagging all the solution.

Comment: Please read this and pay special attention to the section on query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056  Then please [edit] your question  to give more information about your situation.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `GROUP BY` on your query. Is this the actual, _complete_ query?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you described how large the table is, in both rows and columns.

Comment: 13 column and 10M rows

Comment: do I need to upgrade the instance?

Comment: Have you tried using an index like the various answers suggest? Also, you never answered my question of whether this is the actual, complete query. Or showed the query execution plan as one of the answers below requested. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`select DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'Day',sum(people_count) as 'count' from avg_people_pass where log_date >= #startDate and log_date <= #endDate`

I'm guessing you have no indexes configured on this table and that as a result you're doing a full table scan.  3 minute execution time implies a woefully designed, large table with no indexing, keys or optimization.

What happens when you run

`explain select DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'Day',sum(people_count) as 'count' from avg_people_pass where log_date >= #startDate and log_date <= #endDate`

A query plan will help narrow down the performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

This should make it run as fast as it's ever going to, assuming you don't already have an index on this column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON avg_people_pass (log_date);
```